# react-native : Unable to resolve module `tty` from ''.../node_modules/window-size/index.js": Module does not exist in the module map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

> Error

```
    loading dependency graph, done.
    error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `tty` from `/MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/window-size/index.js`: Module does not exist in the module map

    This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
    To resolve try the following:
      1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
      2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
      3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  
      4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
        at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:158:1476)
        at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:92:16)
        at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:271:4465)
        at dependencies.map.relativePath (/MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:379:19)
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at resolveDependencies (/MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:378:16)
        at /MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:203:33
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at step (/MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:296:307)
        at /MyWorks/rnTestTrials/myCurrencySample/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:296:467
     BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 60.2% (291/375), failed.
```

--

I tired the given solution in the error , and delete and re-initiate npm
 and also delete build from `"./ios"` and run again `'react-native run-ios'`

this app working perfectily, but sudden shows this error and stop working,

[image]

tired all npm_module related solutions in the web,

> versions

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.54.0
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "myCurrencySample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "color": "2.0.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "^0.54.0",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

please help,

Comment: It seems error occurred one of your modules. suggestions: 1-) Did you try remove or unlink what you have installed before crashes? 2-) What is the output when you try to build from xcode? 3-) and also you said "this app working perfectily, but sudden shows this error and stop working" what does it mean? App crashes during run time or built time?

Answer (score 23):

I got the exact same error as yours, and i realized that while importing a different module, I accidentally imported this  "import { width } from 'window-size';", this usually happens when IntelliSense is ON, for some IEDs like Visual Studio Code which imports a line of code that you did not intend to put. 
So to answer your question go through your files, probably the last file you were working on, and check if you accidentally imported "window-size" module which you did not intend to import and delete that line of code. And that's the short answer

If you have too many files to go through, then you can temporarily delete window-size folder inside node_modules in your project directory, WARNING DO NOT PERMANENT DELETE, KEEP IT SOMEWHERE SAFE, and make sure to close the metro bundler window, then run "react-native run-android or ios" again, the metro bundler should through an error but this time, the error will show exactly which file in your project has a problem, once you find it, delete that line of code, PUT BACK the window-size folder, 
Then clean your project by running "cd android && ./gradlew clean", close the metro bundler and run "react-native run-android or ios" again, it should work,

DISCLAIMER, This answer is only SPECIFIC to this question, because "Unable to resolve module" ERROR, can be caused by alot of things

Comment: Thank you, i resolve this error by deleting currently working files and ios , Android folders and run command "react-native upgrade ",  ur answer shower much better solution :).. thank you

Comment: Hahaha! This is hilarious! this was literally spot on! Thank you so much!

Comment: This was exactly my problem as well. Thanks for this.